# Jasmine assert call order

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm testing a representation of a NoSQL document in Jasmine. Each document has a `save` method, which saves the changes to the object to the database, and a `reload` method, which loads the document from the database into the object. I'd like to define a `sync` method, which simply calls `save` and then calls `reload`.

My test for this method looks like this (`subject` is the document instance):

```
describe 'sync', ->
  it 'saves and then reloads', ->
    spyOn(subject, 'save')
    spyOn(subject, 'reload')
    subject.sync()
    expect(subject.save).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(subject.reload).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

However, this test is incomplete; it passes for a `sync` method that reloads before saving, which would discard changes made to the document.

How can I assert that the save method is called before the reload method?

Answer (score 5):

One solution I found was to push onto an array instead of using Jasmine spies:

```
describe 'sync', ->
  it 'saves and then reloads', ->
    callOrder = []
    subject.save = -> callOrder.push 'save'
    subject.reload = -> callOrder.push 'reload'
    subject.sync()
    expect(callOrder).toEqual(['save', 'reload'])
```

Comment: Nice idea. In order to keep the spy system, I have used a modified version of your technique by using .and.callFake() and place the callOrder.push in it.